# Usar o retorno da função em um v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando a dias isso, preciso pegar o retorno de uma funçao e colocar ela em um v-model

```
calcBudget(a, b, result) {
            b.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
            let value = b.replace(/[.,]/g, '')
            let c = (value * a / 100)
            c.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
            result = c
            console.log(result)
            return result
        },
```

A função é essa, onde 'a' se refere a um parametro de um v-model e o 'b' outro parametro tbm, nesse caso eu faço uma multiplicação e preciso devolver o resultado em um outro v-model

```
                        <button class="deleteButton" type="button" @click="budgetRemove(index)" v-if="index > 0"><i
                                class="trash icon"></i></button>

                        <row-component>
                            <row-col-component
                                :class-row-col="'col-xxl-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12'"
                                :class="{ 'formError': errors.name }">
                                <label>Produto/Serviço:</label>
                                <input-component :type-input="'text'" v-model="budget.service"
                                    :model-value="budget.service">
                                </input-component>
                            </row-col-component>

                            <row-col-component
                                :class-row-col="'col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12'"
                                :class="{ 'formError': errors.status }">
                                <label>Quantidade:</label>
                                <input-number-component :type-input="'number'" v-model="budget.amount"
                                    :model-value="budget.amount"></input-number-component>
                            </row-col-component>

                            <row-col-component
                                :class-row-col="'col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12'"
                                :class="{ 'formError': errors.price }">
                                <label>Valor Unitário:</label>
                                <input-component :type-input="'text'" v-model="budget.unitary"
                                    :model-value="budget.unitary" v-money="money">
                                </input-component>
                            </row-col-component>
                            <row-col-component
                                :class-row-col="'col-xxl-2 col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12'"
                                :class="{ 'formError': errors.price }">
                                <label>Valor:</label>
                                <input-component :type-input="'text'" v-model.lazy="budget.final_value"
                                    @focus="calcBudget(budget.amount, budget.unitary, budget.final_value)">
                                </input-component>

                            </row-col-component>
                        </row-component>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

esse é o bloco onde esta a função

No momento tentei devolver o ultimo parametro e pegar de volta no v-model mas tbm não deu certo

Comment: Parece tech support

Answer (score 0):

O comportamento esperado pode não estar funcionando como o esperado devido a forma como a propriedade budget estiver sendo declarada.

Com a Composition API do Vue 3, por padrão as propriedades não são reativas, é preciso utiliza envolvê-las com `ref()` ou `reactive()` para que apresentem um comportamento reativo e o Two-Way Data Biding do v-model funcione:

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

let budget = reactive({
  amount: 10,
  unitary: 2,
  final_value: undefined
});

const calcBudget = () => {
  budget.final_value = (budget.unitary * budget.amount) / 100;
  console.log(budget);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="number" v-model="budget.amount" :model-value="budget.amount" placeholder="Quantidade">
    <input type="number" v-model="budget.unitary" :model-value="budget.unitary" @keyup="calcBudget()" placeholder="Valor unitário">
    <input type="number" v-model="budget.final_value"  placeholder="Valor total">

    {{budget}}
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 12px;
}
</style>
```